# Finding a fullmatch in array by ignoring some in string which is not in array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays, match

I am trying to match a string to array but still my string contains some other contents so my script is not finding the exact match

```
public class find
{
string[] stores = {"Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St, Santa Monica, CA 90401", "802 N San Vicente Blvd, West Hollywood, CA 90069", "7726 Melrose Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90046", "1060 Westwood Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90024", "6922 Hollywood Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90028","363 E 2nd St, Los Angeles, CA 90012","747 Warehouse St, Los Angeles, CA 90021","2654 Main St, Santa Monica, CA 90405"};

string value_to_find = "walter,6922 Hollywood Blvd.
 Los Angeles, CA 90028";

 if(stores.Contains(store_tran1))
                        {
                        Console.Write("Found");
                        }
}
```

How to ignore the values from the string which is not in the array and find the exact match in c#?

Comment: edited question do you understand now??

Comment: wouldn't the equals method do the job?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class find
{
  string[] stores = {"Third Street Promenade, 1220 3rd St, Santa Monica, CA 90401", "802 N San Vicente Blvd, West Hollywood, CA 90069", "7726 Melrose Ave, Los Angeles, CA 90046", "1060 Westwood Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90024", "6922 Hollywood Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90028","363 E 2nd St, Los Angeles, CA 90012","747 Warehouse St, Los Angeles, CA 90021","2654 Main St, Santa Monica, CA 90405"};

  string value_to_find = "walter,6922 Hollywood Blvd. Los Angeles, CA 90028";

  foreach(var found in stores.Where(x => x.Equals(value_to_find)))
  {
    Console.Write("Found");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to turn it around. ForEach entry in stores, see if value_to_find contains the entry, using String.Contains. That is look for store in value, not value in store.

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var stores = new List<string>{"aaa","bbb","ccc"};
        var searchValue = "xxx,aaa"; // should find store "aaa"

        foreach(var store in stores){
            if(searchValue.Contains(store)){
                Console.WriteLine(string.Format("found - {0}",store));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output: found - aaa